# Passing and receiving multiple arguments with Python in Flask RestAPI

Tags: python, rest, curl

I am clearly confused but not sure if I am screwing up the code, or curl

I would like to use a rest api to pass a schemaname, a queryname, and a number of rows. I've written the python code using a simple -s schemaname -q queryname -r rows structure. Thats seems easy enough. But I  am having trouble finding a good example of passing multiple arguments in a restapi. No matter which version of the todos example I choose as a model, I just cannot figure out how to extend for the second and 3rd argument. If it uses a different structure (JSON) for input, I am fine. The only requirement is that it run from CURL. I can find examples of passing lists, but not multiple arguments.

If there is a code example that does it and i have missed it, please send me along. As long as it has a curl example I am good.

Thank you

Comment: How does the API accept parameters? As query parameters? Encoded in the body?

Answer (score 0):

I am nominally embarrassed. The issue was NOT the python code at all, it was within Curl. So I both switched to HTTPie and changed the format to Schema=LONGSCHEMANAME

All of my tests started working so clearly I was not specifying the right string in curl. The -d option was beating me. So I apologize for wasting time. Thanks